# Class that handles unique IDs for specific Items -> abstract or not?

Tags: java, object, abstract

I am fairly new to programming, especially the OOP concept. I created a class that should handle unique IDs for another classes objects. I just want to assign an unique ID to an object in its constructor.

I have no clue if the `IdHandler` class should be abstract or not. As far as I understand, if I need different namespaces for the IDs (maybe for different warehouses), I need to create an `IdHandler` object for each one? Where do I create those objects? At the beginning of the main class or in the constructor that defines the namespace (e.g. `Warehouse()`)?

That is the ID class ->

```
public class IdHandler {

    private String newId;
    private ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();


    public String getId() {

        this.newId = "";
        while (this.newId == "") {
            this.newId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            // if doesn't exist already , add to list, else empty String
            if (!this.idList.contains(this.newId)) {
                this.idList.add(this.newId);
                break;
            }

            else
                this.newId = "";
        }
        return this.newId;

    }
}
```

Comment: If it is abstract you won't be able to instantiate it. If you only want to inherit from it, then that's ok, but there is no indication of that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Find it unclear if your class supposed to hold the ID of an object or if it's used to generate unique ID that the object will then hold itself.

Following your code I supposed your class is used only to generate new ID. In this case your class is used as a Utility class. So you don't want to make it abstract. Abstract means "should be extended" or a utility class should not be extended, you could make it final to avoid subclass.

Then you want the list of IDs to be stored and shared to everyon so you don't reuse the IDs. So you have to make it static. After the variable newId is reset at every call to getId(). So you could make it local to the method. Finally make the method static so it does not require an instance of IdHandler so it will be the same for everyone calling this method.

In this case I think the method could be renamed (to be more explicit on what it does) to `getNewId()`

```
public final class IdHandler {

    private static ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static String getNewId() {
        newId = "";
        while (newId == "") {
            newId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            // if doesn't exist already , add to list, else empty String
            if (!idList.contains(newId)) {
                idList.add(newId);
                break;
            }
            else
                newId = "";
        }
        return newId;
    }
}
```

And to call the method :

```
public static void main() {
    String myId = IdHandler.getNewId();
}
```

---

*Edit following this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792804/class-that-handles-unique-ids-for-specific-items-abstract-or-not/49793454#comment86609399_49793454) :*

If you want different IdHandler for different objects. For example you want an ID handler for the dog object and one for the cat object. So a dog and a cat could have the same ID, which not a problem since their not instances of the same class.

You could think of create simple instances of IdHandler for each one but it will not be the best since you will have to pass the reference to the instance everywhere you want to create new ID.

Instead you could "hide" an instance of IdHandler for each type of object (in other words for each class), one in Dog and one in Cat, by making a static field in the class that refer to the IdHandler instance. By doing this you will have an instance for each class (dog or cat) and you will access it directly from the class cause it's static.

First modify your IdHandler class to not keep static field cause you don't want them shared between the dog instance and the cat instance.

public class IdHandler {

```
    private ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getNewId() {
        newId = "";
        while (newId == "") {
            newId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            // if doesn't exist already , add to list, else empty String
            if (!idList.contains(newId)) {
                idList.add(newId);
                break;
            }
            else
                newId = "";
        }
        return newId;
    }
}
```

Then add a static field in the classes that need ID to refer to their instance of IdHandler

```
Public class Dog {
    public static final idHanlder = new IdHandler();

    private final id;

    public Dog(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String bark() {
        return "waf!";
    }
}

public class Cat {
    public static final idHanlder = new IdHandler();

    private final id;

    public Cat(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String Meow() {
        return "meow";
    } 
}
```

The IdHandler will be created when the class Dog (or Cat) is created and will be shared between all instances of Dog (or Cat). And you can access it directly from the class Dog (or Cat).

```
public void main() {
    String dogId1 = Dog.idHandler.getNewId();
    Dog dog1 = new Dog(dogId1);
    String dogId2 = Dog.idHandler.getNewId();
    Dog dog2 = new Dog(dogId2);
    String catId1 = Cat.idHandler.getNewId();
    Cat cat1 = new Cat(catId1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yes the plan is to create multiple objects of a specific item ( in this case a shipping container ) and each object should store its own unique ID which it gets from the IdHandler.  My concern is , lets say,  i want to expand my project and create another type of object with its own namespace of uniqueIDs . to my understanding i then would have to create instances of the IdHandler ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends if you want to instantiate your class or not.
For a class like your IdHandler it doesn't make sense to be abstract.

The idea of abstract classes is that they define common fields and methods that inheriting classes can use, but should not be instantiatable on their own.

But if you are using UUIDs, then your whole IdHandler is superfluous. It's a good idea to have a class handle the ID generation. But it is really not necessary to save them to a list or check if they are in that list (which btw. is not the ideal data structure because lookups are slow, it's better to use a HashSet).

The Idea behind a UUID is that when you generate one it is unique. There is the theoretical possibility of a collision, but the odds are so small that it is more likely that one gets hit by a meteorite.

Also, why would you return an empty string if there was a collision? If that ever were to happen (it most likely never will), you would probably want to know that and throw an exception.

So my suggestion for you:

```
public class IdGenerator {

    public static String generateId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```